# Jobs executed using at command hangs

Tags: bash, at-job

I have bash script test.sh which runs a simple command as below

```
echo "test" >> /d2/tmp/test.txt
```

Now I invoke this as below

```
[root@labtspc1rg03 tmp]# at now < test.sh
job 574 at 2015-12-30 05:26
```

Now this job never gets executed.

```
[root@labtspc1rg03 tmp]# atq
574     2015-12-30 05:26 = root
573     2015-12-30 05:26 = root
```

there were 2 jobs which i had scheduled,if you notice there is an equal sign in each job
If I understand correctly equal means that its currently running job but there is no output for the job seen i.e output is empty.
I expected output of every job is sent to /var/spool/at/spool/

```
[root@labtspc1rg03 spool]# cat a0023e017120d2
Subject: Output from your job      574
To: root
<EMPTY>
```

There are no privileges set either in /etc/at.deny or /etc/at.allow file.

I would like to know what can I check to get the reason why this job was not executed and also I noticed that the job exited on it's own after some 2 hours or so, is there some default config which triggered this?

Comment: Is it because you are writing `echo test` to `test.txt` & reading from `test.sh`? :P

Comment: echo test to text.txt is the content of test.sh. And I think it's something that is happening in particularly on that box, I try the same on other box and things works just fine

Comment: For `cron`/`at` jobs, the PATH variable is set to a minimal `PATH`. `echo` should be resolved, because `/bin/sh` would have a built-in `echo`.

Comment: Check if the require path - `/d2/tmp/test.txt` is mounted... Also, check if there are any permission issues. Try running commands like `which mount | at now`.

Answer (score 1):

`at now < test.sh` executes `test.sh` immediately and then sends the  *output* of `test.sh` into `at`. So `at` will then execute `test`.

To execute the `test.sh` script, you can do either:

```
echo "/path/to/your/script/test.sh" | at now
```

or

```
at -f "/path/to/your/script/test.sh" now
```

Comment: I used this echo just for test purpose.. no matter what I execute using "at" the same hangs.. and not sure how that gets cleared after two hours or so